# Shell Script to take the values falling between two years

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm working with a small bash code which is working fine but i'm just looking if there is better way to formalise the awk piece ie below, which is looking for the Files between year 2002 and 2018 on the column eight.

> `$AWK" '$8 >= "2002" && $8<= "2018"' "$FILE`

### Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="/home/pygo/Cyberark/ftplogs_3"
AWK="/bin/awk"
GREP="/bin/grep"
USERS="`"$AWK" '$8 >= "2002" && $8<= "2018"' $FILE | "$AWK" '{print $3}' | sort -u`"
for user in $USERS;
do
echo "User $user " | tr -d "\n";
"$AWK" '$8 >= "2002" && $8<= "2018"' "$FILE" | "$GREP" "$user" | "$AWK" '{ total += $5}; END { print "Total Space consumed: "  total/1024/1024/1024 "GB"}';
done | column -t
echo ""
echo "=============================================================="
"$AWK" '$8 >= "2002" && $8<= "2018"' "$FILE" | "$AWK" '{ total += $5}; END { print "Total Space consumed by All Users: "  total/1024/1024/1024 "GB"}';
echo ""
```

### Result:

```
User  16871                   Total  Space  consumed:  0.0905161GB
User  253758                  Total  Space  consumed:  0.0750855GB
User  34130                   Total  Space  consumed:  3.52537GB
User  36640                   Total  Space  consumed:  0.55393GB
User  8490                    Total  Space  consumed:  3.70858GB
User  tx-am                   Total  Space  consumed:  0.18992GB
User  tx-ffv                  Total  Space  consumed:  0.183137GB
User  tx-ttv                  Total  Space  consumed:  17.2371GB
User  tx-st                   Total  Space  consumed:  0.201205GB
User  tx-ti                   Total  Space  consumed:  58.9704GB
User  tx-tts                 Total  Space  consumed:  0.0762068GB

------------ snipped output --------------
==============================================================
Total Space consumed by All Users: 255.368GB
```

### Edit: sample data

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 34130 ftpsecure 101M Mar 26  2007 /data1/focus-del/files_1
-rw-r--r-- 1 34130 ftpsecure 172M Oct 13  2005 /data1/focus-del/files_2
-rw-r--r-- 1 34130 ftpsecure 213M Nov  8  2005 /data1/focus-del/files_3
-rw-r--r-- 1 34130 ftpsecure 138M Feb 17  2006 /data1/focus-del/files_4
-rw-r--r-- 1 34130 ftpsecure 169M Sep 26  2016 /data1/focus-del/files_5
-rw-r--r-- 1 34130 ftpsecure 214M Nov 15  2018 /data1/focus-del/files_6
-rw-r--r-- 1 34130 ftpsecure 101M Mar 26  2002 /data2/focus-del/files_1
-rw-r--r-- 1 34130 ftpsecure 172M Oct 13  2006 /data2/focus-del/files_2
-rw-r--r-- 1 34130 ftpsecure 213M Nov  8  2008 /data2/focus-del/files_3
-rw-r--r-- 1 34130 ftpsecure 138M Feb 17  2016 /data2/focus-del/files_4
-rw-r--r-- 1 34130 ftpsecure 169M Sep 26  2018 /data2/focus-del/files_5
-rw-r--r-- 1 34130 ftpsecure 214M Nov 15  2018 /data2/focus-del/files_6
```

### Expected Output:

```
$ sh Ftp_cal.sh
User  34130  Total  Space  consumed:  1.87568e-06GB

==============================================================
Total Space consumed by All Users: 1.87568e-06GB
```

Comment: @anubhava,  i have update with the sample data.

Comment: Please add expected output matching the provided `sample data`/

Comment: Note that while you may get a response here, this kind of question where you've got a functional piece of code you would like to improve is more on topic on the [CodeReview SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @anubhava, added the output expected from sample data.

Comment: @Aaron, you are absolutely right, i'll take this advice in consideration going forward.

Comment: @pygo: Total of 5th columns is `2014` so unclear you are showing `Space  consumed:  1.87568e-06GB` in expected output.

Comment: @anubhava, you can have your result.. may may i missed somewhere , sorry for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `awk` script:

```
awk '$8 >= 2002 && $8 <= 2018 {
   sum[$3] += $5
}
END {
   for (i in sum) {
      printf "User  %s  Total  Space  consumed: %d\n", i, sum[i]
      total += sum[i]
   }
   print "==============="
   print "Total Space consumed by All Users:", total
}' file
```

```
User  34130  Total  Space  consumed: 2014
===============
Total Space consumed by All Users: 2014
```